# Why difference in C# tab and comma delimited split?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, split

I have a Excel Spreadsheet that has 10 columns.  Not all cells contain data.  If I save it as a tab-delimited file and use Split() (as shown below) I will get different results than when I save it as a comma-delimited file and it will return an IndexOutOfBounds Exception.

If I do something like:

```
String tabSepartor = "\t";
lineTokens = inputLine.Split(tabSepartor.ToCharArray());
int lineTokensLength = lineTokens.Length;
```

On the tab-delimited file, I'll get results that are either 8 or 10 in length, but if I do it using a comma-delimiter it will always show 10.

```
String commaSeparator = ",";
lineTokens = inputLine.Split(commaSeparator.ToCharArray());
```

How do I get the tab-delimited Split() to work the same as the comma-delimited split?

EDIT (as requested):
Here is the comma delimited line:

```
Info,Info,1/1,select,Yes,Info,Info,Info,,
```

Here is the tab delimited line:

```
Info    Info    1/1 select  Yes Info    Info    Info
```

Comment: the difference is probably because of the state of the file, or better, its format. Some how it has more tabs that commas. Imo, the only reasonable solution, is to change the file format accordingly.

Comment: @Tigran - Great suggestion, but the files are the same, the same tabs and commas

Comment: In Excel i did find the option to save the file with a tab separator  `\t` or with semicolon `;` separator. I did not find an option to save with a comma-separator `,` Are you sure the file is saved with `,` and not with `;`?

Comment: I suspect your lines are not the same. Given the string `"hello,,world"`, splitting on comma gives me 3 items. Given the string `"hello\t\tworld"`, splitting on tab gives 3 items. If you can show us a working example where two lines that differ only in that the commas are replaced with tabs, and they provide different results from splitting, then post it. Otherwise, your problem is somewhere else. Unless you're using an earlier version of .NET (I tested with .NET 4.5) that has a bug in the `String.Split` method. I don't know of any such thing. What version of .NET are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimited files can still contain delimiters within the actual data

```
First,Second,Third,"Fourth, then more",Fifth
```

Because of this, you should use the [TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx) class of .NET. It is slower than `Split` but will handle parsing out your CSV correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply. The reason I'm moving to a tab-delimited solution is because sometimes people fill out the Spreadsheet and when they do, they put a comma in their data.  When I parse the Spreadsheet that is saved as a CSV, if it comes across that comma that was input, it breaks the parsing.   I was hoping to give them the ability to use commas by moving it to a tab-delimited solution.  Could I accomplish the same by using the TextFieldParser class?

Comment: @Mark Yes, that it what `TextFieldParser` is designed for. When the exported CSV contains the delimiter in the data itself, it will export with quotes around it. `TextFieldParser` has a flag you set to handle these quotes correctly.

Comment: @Mark The property is `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes`. Take look at the MSDN page, it should tell you everything you need to know

Comment: Thanks a bunch.  That was a real help!